# How could msvcp140d.dll cause error for integer comparison?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, directx-11

I am working on a DirectX11 application on VS2015. Recently I have encountered a runtime error caused by this msvcp140d.dll library. The call stack when the error occurred is shown below:
[image]

And the code generating the error is shown below:
[image]

As far as I could tell the values for the variables were acceptable, so I am not sure exactly what has caused this msvcp140d.dll to break at this line of code. Does it mean that this dll might be incorrect? Or something else has gone wrong?

The function with error is my implementation of A* algorithm.

```
vector<pair<int, int>> NavigationManager::pathFinding(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) const{
vector<pair<int, int>> path;
if (startX == endX&&startY == endY)
    return path;

Node ***nodeMap = new Node**[mapHeight];
for (int i = 0; i<mapHeight; ++i)
{
    nodeMap[i] = new Node*[mapWidth];
    for (int j = 0; j<mapWidth; ++j)
    {
        if (map[i][j] != 1) {
            nodeMap[i][j] = new Node(j, i);
            nodeMap[i][j]->hValue = (abs(endX - j) + abs(endY - i)) * 10;
        }
        else
            nodeMap[i][j] = nullptr;
    }
}

auto comp = [](Node *a, Node *b) {return (a->gValue + a->hValue) > (b->gValue + a->hValue); };
priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, decltype(comp)> pq(comp);
vector<Node*> v;
int currentX, currentY, currentGValue;
Node *currentParent = nullptr;
do
{
    if (pq.empty())
    {
        currentX = startX;
        currentY = startY;
        currentGValue = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        currentParent = pq.top();
        currentX = currentParent->x;
        currentY = currentParent->y;
        currentGValue = currentParent->gValue;
        v.push_back(currentParent);
        pq.pop();
    }
    if (currentX == endX&&currentY == endY)
        break;

    if (currentX<mapWidth - 1 && map[currentY][currentX + 1] != 1)
    {
        if (nodeMap[currentY][currentX + 1]->gValue == 0)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY][currentX + 1]->gValue = currentGValue + 10;
            nodeMap[currentY][currentX + 1]->parent = currentParent;
            pq.push(nodeMap[currentY][currentX + 1]);
        }
        else if (currentGValue + 10<nodeMap[currentY][currentX + 1]->gValue)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY][currentX + 1]->gValue = currentGValue + 10;
            nodeMap[currentY][currentX + 1]->parent = currentParent;
        }
    }

    if (currentX<mapWidth - 1 && map[currentY][currentX + 1] != 1 && currentY<mapHeight - 1 && map[currentY + 1][currentX] != 1 && map[currentY + 1][currentX + 1] != 1)
    {
        if (nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX + 1]->gValue == 0)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX + 1]->gValue = currentGValue + 14;
            nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX + 1]->parent = currentParent;
            pq.push(nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX + 1]);
        }
        else if (currentGValue + 14<nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX + 1]->gValue)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX + 1]->gValue = currentGValue + 14;
            nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX + 1]->parent = currentParent;
        }
    }

    if (currentY<mapHeight - 1 && map[currentY + 1][currentX] != 1)
    {
        if (nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX]->gValue == 0)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX]->gValue = currentGValue + 10;
            nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX]->parent = currentParent;
            pq.push(nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX]);
        }
        else if (currentGValue + 10<nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX]->gValue)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX]->gValue = currentGValue + 10;
            nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX]->parent = currentParent;
        }
    }

    if (currentX>0 && map[currentY][currentX - 1] != 1 && currentY<mapHeight - 1 && map[currentY + 1][currentX] != 1 && map[currentY + 1][currentX - 1] != 1)
    {
        if (nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX - 1]->gValue == 0)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX - 1]->gValue = currentGValue + 14;
            nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX - 1]->parent = currentParent;
            pq.push(nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX - 1]);
        }
        else if (currentGValue + 14<nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX - 1]->gValue)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX - 1]->gValue = currentGValue + 14;
            nodeMap[currentY + 1][currentX - 1]->parent = currentParent;
        }
    }

    if (currentX>0 && map[currentY][currentX - 1] != 1)
    {
        if (nodeMap[currentY][currentX - 1]->gValue == 0)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY][currentX - 1]->gValue = currentGValue + 10;
            nodeMap[currentY][currentX - 1]->parent = currentParent;
            pq.push(nodeMap[currentY][currentX - 1]);
        }
        else if (currentGValue + 10<nodeMap[currentY][currentX - 1]->gValue)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY][currentX - 1]->gValue = currentGValue + 10;
            nodeMap[currentY][currentX - 1]->parent = currentParent;
        }
    }

    if (currentX>0 && map[currentY][currentX - 1] != 1 && currentY>0 && map[currentY - 1][currentX] != 1 && map[currentY - 1][currentX - 1] != 1)
    {
        if (nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX - 1]->gValue == 0)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX - 1]->gValue = currentGValue + 14;
            nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX - 1]->parent = currentParent;
            pq.push(nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX - 1]);
        }
        else if (currentGValue + 14<nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX - 1]->gValue)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX - 1]->gValue = currentGValue + 14;
            nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX - 1]->parent = currentParent;
        }
    }

    if (currentY>0 && map[currentY - 1][currentX] != 1)
    {
        if (nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX]->gValue == 0)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX]->gValue = currentGValue + 10;
            nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX]->parent = currentParent;
            pq.push(nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX]);
        }
        else if (currentGValue + 10<nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX]->gValue)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX]->gValue = currentGValue + 10;
            nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX]->parent = currentParent;
        }
    }

    if (currentX<mapWidth - 1 && map[currentY][currentX + 1] != 1 && currentY>0 && map[currentY - 1][currentX] != 1 && map[currentY - 1][currentX + 1] != 1)
    {
        if (nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX + 1]->gValue == 0)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX + 1]->gValue = currentGValue + 14;
            nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX + 1]->parent = currentParent;
            pq.push(nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX + 1]);
        }
        else if (currentGValue + 14<nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX + 1]->gValue)
        {
            nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX + 1]->gValue = currentGValue + 14;
            nodeMap[currentY - 1][currentX + 1]->parent = currentParent;
        }
    }
} while (!pq.empty());

if (v.size() == 0 || v[v.size() - 1]->x != endX || v[v.size() - 1]->y != endY)
    return path;

stack<pair<int, int>> s;
if (!v.empty())
{
    Node *destination = v[v.size() - 1];
    while (destination)
    {
        s.push(pair<int, int>(destination->x, destination->y));
        destination = destination->parent;
    }
}
while (!s.empty())
{
    path.push_back(s.top());
    s.pop();
}
for (int i = 0; i<mapHeight; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<mapWidth; ++j)
    {
        delete nodeMap[i][j];
    }
    delete[] nodeMap[i];
}
delete[] nodeMap;

return path;
```

}

Comment: This library is a C++ runtime library, and it is extremely unlikely there is a problem with it. Look for problems in your own code.

Comment: Line 81 is just where execution of this function will resume when whatever function has been called returns.  Possibly `pq.pop();`.  Post your code as code, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You're altering the sort key of objects in your priority queue.

Looking at a typical case, if a node's `gValue` is zero, you assign it a `gValue` and add (a pointer to) it to the priority queue.  Later, you potentially change that `gValue` while the node is still in the priority queue.  This can cause the sort order to be all messed up, breaks the ordering the container is relying on, and who knows what will happen then.  This is why `priority_queue::top()` returns a const reference.

If you need to change an element that is already in `pq`, you need to remove it, change the value, then add it back.